# pivot_table on multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

How can I apply pandas.pivot_table to the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 897, 'colname': 'col1', 'colvalue': 'sfjdka'},
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 897, 'colname': 'col2', 'colvalue': 25},
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 159, 'colname': 'col1', 'colvalue': 'laksjd'},
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 159, 'colname': 'col2', 'colvalue': 26}
]
```

)

to get a multi-indexed result (indexed by o1_pkid and o2_pkid), where the columns come from **colname** and the values come from **colvalue**?  I am looking to get a result something like:

```
colname                 col1          col2
o1_pkid      o2_pkid 
645          897      'sfjdka'      25
             159      'laksjd'      26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['o1_pkid', 'o2_pkid', 'colname'])['colvalue'].unstack()

print (df)
colname            col1 col2
o1_pkid o2_pkid             
645     159      laksjd   26
        897      sfjdka   25
```

But if get error:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

need:

[`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with some aggregate function like `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 897, 'colname': 'col1', 'colvalue': 'sfjdka'},
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 897, 'colname': 'col2', 'colvalue': 25},
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 159, 'colname': 'col1', 'colvalue': 'laksjd'},
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 159, 'colname': 'col2', 'colvalue': 10},
    {'o1_pkid': 645, 'o2_pkid': 159, 'colname': 'col2', 'colvalue': 26}
])


df = df.pivot_table(index=['o1_pkid', 'o2_pkid'], 
                        columns='colname', 
                        values='colvalue', 
                        aggfunc='sum')
print (df)
colname            col1 col2
o1_pkid o2_pkid             
645     159      laksjd   36
        897      sfjdka   25
```

or `groupby` + `aggregate function` + `unstack`:

```
df = df.groupby(['o1_pkid', 'o2_pkid', 'colname'])['colvalue'].sum().unstack()

print (df)
colname            col1 col2
o1_pkid o2_pkid             
645     159      laksjd   36
        897      sfjdka   25
```